# Where is the charts_flutter documentation?

Tags: flutter, charts, documentation

I am trying to customize a `charts_flutter` graph - I want to display the current line graph value that the user is hovering over.

Is there any good documentation for `charts_flutter` or `charts_common`? The best thing I can find is the gallery:

https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/gallery.html

There seem to be some advanced examples in the "behaviors" section at the bottom. But I can't seem to find any documentation that describes all the available concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach [charts_flutter_new](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter_new) instead of charts_flutter.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [fl_chart](https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart). It's an excellent library, it has the configuration you want, and it's pretty customizable. I've used it a few times and recommend it.